# Parrot Ar Drone connection with a CC3000 WiFi shield for Arduino

Tags: connection, udp, arduino, packets

So I'm trying to control a Parrot AR drone from an arduino that is using a CC3000 WiFi shield as it's means of communcation with the drone.

I've managed to connect to the drone's WiFi Access Point, go through the DHCP etc and actually connect to the control and communication ports 5556, 5554.

The drone communicates using UDP and I've used the Adafruit libraries for the CC3000 shield to make a UDP connection with these ports.

I can't however seem to get the drone to talk to me or to even send commands to the drone :'(

The drone accepts text strings in a certain format to control the various functions like takeoff, land etc. and I've tried to send these strings via UDP but to no avail.

Here's My code in Arduino:

```
#include <Adafruit_CC3000.h>
#include <ccspi.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <String.h>
#include "utility/debug.h"

#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ    3
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT   5
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS     10
#define WLAN_SSID              "ardrone_000000"  
#define WLAN_PASS              ""  
#define WLAN_SECURITY          WLAN_SEC_UNSEC 
#define ARDRONE_NAVDATA_PORT                5554
#define ARDRONE_VIDEO_PORT                  5555
#define ARDRONE_AT_PORT                     5556
#define ARDRONE_CONFIGDATA_PORT             5559
#define ARDRONE_MAX_AT_COMMAND_LENGTH        300
#define ARDRONE_AT_CMD_INTERVAL               30

Adafruit_CC3000 cc3000 = Adafruit_CC3000(ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS, ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ,ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT, SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER);
uint32_t ipAddress, netmask, gateway, dhcpserv, dnsserv;
/*
int longtime = 0;
const unsigned long connectTimeout = 4L * 100L, // Max time to wait for the serverconnection
responseTimeout = 4L * 100L; //Max time to wait for answer from server*/
char cmd[ARDRONE_MAX_AT_COMMAND_LENGTH];
int sequence = 0;
int run_count = 0;
char inBuffer[255];
char outBuffer[] = "acknowledged";

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);

Serial.println(F("\nInitialising the CC3000..."));
  if (!cc3000.begin()) {
    Serial.println(F("Unable to initialise the CC3000! Check your wiring?"));
    while(1);
  }

Serial.println(F("\nDeleting old connection profiles"));
  if (!cc3000.deleteProfiles()) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed!"));
    while(1);
  }

char *ssid = WLAN_SSID;
Serial.print(F("\nAttempting to connect to ")); 
Serial.print(ssid);

if (!cc3000.connectToAP(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS, WLAN_SECURITY)) {
  Serial.println(F("Failed!"));
  while(1);
}

Serial.println(F("\nConnected!"));
Serial.println(F("\nRequest DHCP"));
while (!cc3000.checkDHCP()) {
delay(1000);
}
connect_drone();
}

void loop() {
 talkToDrone();
}

void connect_drone() {
 cc3000.getIPAddress(&ipAddress, &netmask, &gateway, &dhcpserv, &dnsserv);
 Adafruit_CC3000_Client drone_config = cc3000.connectTCP(ipAddress,   ARDRONE_CONFIGDATA_PORT);
Adafruit_CC3000_Client drone_control = cc3000.connectUDP(ipAddress, ARDRONE_AT_PORT);
Adafruit_CC3000_Client drone_comms = cc3000.connectUDP(ipAddress,   ARDRONE_NAVDATA_PORT);
  if (drone_comms.connected()) {
    Serial.println(F("Drone talking"));
  } else {
  Serial.println(F("Drone not talking"));
 }
  if (drone_control.available()) {
  Serial.println(F("Drone ready for Commands"));
  } else {
  Serial.print(F("Drone having none of it..."));
  }
 if (drone_config.connected()) {
 Serial.println(F("Drone Configged"));
 } else { 
 Serial.println(F("Drone not Configged"));
   }
 }  

/*
 Serial.println(F("Closing Comms"));
 drone_comms.close();
 Serial.println(F("-----------------------------------------------------------"));*/


void nav_data_init() {
Adafruit_CC3000_Client drone_comms = cc3000.connectUDP(ipAddress, ARDRONE_NAVDATA_PORT);
if (drone_comms.connected()) {
  //drone_comms.print("AT*CONFIG=general:navdata_demo,TRUE\r");
  //drone_comms.print("AT*CTRL=0\r");
}

 if (drone_comms.connected()) {
 if (drone_comms.available()) {
   Serial.println(F("Receiving Telemetry Data"));
    char c = drone_comms.read();
   Serial.print(c);
   }
 }
}

void takeOff() {
  snprintf(cmd , strlen(cmd), "AT*REF=%d,290718208\r", sequence++);//add \r
 }

void land() {
  snprintf(cmd , strlen(cmd), "AT*REF=%d,290717696\r", sequence++);
 }

void hover() {
  snprintf(cmd , strlen(cmd), "AT*PCMD=%d,1,0,0,0,0\r", sequence++);
 }

void calib() {
  snprintf(cmd, strlen(cmd), "AT*FTRIM=%d\r", sequence++);
 }

void watchdog() {
  snprintf(cmd, strlen(cmd), "AT*COMWDG\r", sequence++);
 }

void periodicTask() {
  unsigned long current_t = millis();
  static unsigned long next_t = 0;
  if (current_t > next_t) {
    talkToDrone();
    next_t = current_t + ARDRONE_AT_CMD_INTERVAL;
    }
   }

 void talkToDrone() {
 Adafruit_CC3000_Client drone_control = cc3000.connectUDP(ipAddress, ARDRONE_AT_PORT);
 Adafruit_CC3000_Client drone_comms = cc3000.connectUDP(ipAddress, ARDRONE_NAVDATA_PORT);
 if (drone_comms.available()) {
  drone_comms.write(outBuffer, strlen(outBuffer));
  int len = drone_comms.read(inBuffer,255);
  if (len > 0) inBuffer[len] = 0;

  Serial.print("Received packet");
  Serial.println("Contents");
  Serial.println(inBuffer);

  drone_comms.write(outBuffer, strlen(outBuffer));
 }

 if (drone_control.connected() && run_count == 0) {
  Serial.print(F("Sending Takeoff Sequence."));
   calib();
   takeOff();
   watchdog();
   drone_control.print(cmd);
   cmd[0] = 0;
   Serial.print(F("."));
  Serial.println(F(".Done!"));
   run_count++;
   sequence = 0;
  } else if (drone_control.connected() && run_count > 0) {
   Serial.print(F("Sending Hover Sequence."));
   hover();
   watchdog();
   drone_control.print(cmd);
   cmd[0] = 0;
   Serial.print(F("."));
   Serial.println(F(".Done!"));
    run_count++;
    sequence = 0;
  }
 }
```